# Converting Code Into Object Oriented Class

Tags: python, class, opencv, oop

I have a block of code which successfully tracks and outputs the position of the object. [Here's a video of it working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwegubc5AVE). I would like to convert this code into a class, as I'm planning to have multiple cameras whose positions I need to keep track of. Here's the code that runs successfully:

```
import cv2
import easygui

conversionFactor = float(easygui.enterbox("Please enter the numerical conversion factor, in micrometers/pixel:"))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Fast frame rate, low accuracy
#tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
#Slow frame rate, high accuracy
tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

success, img = cap.read()
bbox = cv2.selectROI("Tracking", img, False)
tracker.init(img, bbox)

def drawBox(img, bbox):

    # Get coordinates.
    # x is the pixel value corresponding to horizontal movement of the object.
    # (i.e. x = 0 is the far left of the screen, bigger number is further to the right)
    # y is the pixel value corresponding to vertical movement of the object.
    x,y,w,h = int(bbox[0]),int(bbox[1]),int(bbox[2]),int(bbox[3])
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),((x+w),(y+h)),(255,0,255),3,1)
    cv2.putText(img, "Tracking", (25, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 255), 2)


while True:
    timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    success, img = cap.read()
    xCoordinate = bbox[0] * conversionFactor
    yCoordinate = bbox[1] * conversionFactor
    xCoordinateString = "X Coordinate (micrometers): " + str("%.2f" % xCoordinate)
    yCoordinateString = "Y Coordinate (micrometers): " + str("%.2f" % yCoordinate)
    success, bbox = tracker.update(img)

    if success:
        drawBox(img, bbox)
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "Lost", (25, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency()/(cv2.getTickCount()-timer)
    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (25,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7,(0,0,255),2)
    cv2.putText(img, xCoordinateString, (200, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, yCoordinateString, (200, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Tracking",img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
```

I tried moving all the code in the "while true" block into it's own method, then turn the xCoordinate and yCoordinate variables into horizontalCoordinate and verticalCoordinate class attributes (as it'll be coder defined whether the vertical/horizontal coordinate is the x, y or z axis). The first part of the code runs, but then the video doesn't continue to run ([as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyq-pNHSEyg)).

Would love help troubleshooting this code, in addition to getting some inputs as to how I could improve this class. My skills with Object Oriented design are minimal at best, so I'm sure there are plenty of best practices I'm screwing up here.

The code:

```
import cv2
import easygui

class MachineVisionCamerasAFAM():
    def __init__(self, cameraNumber):
        self.cameraNumber = cameraNumber
        self.horizontalPosition = 0
        self.verticalPosition = 0

        conversionFactor = float(easygui.enterbox("Please enter the numerical conversion factor, in micrometers/pixel:"))
        self.conversionFactor = conversionFactor

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraNumber)
        self.cap = cap

        # Fast frame rate, low accuracy
        # tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        # Slow frame rate, high accuracy
        tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

        success, img = cap.read()
        bbox = cv2.selectROI("Tracking", img, False)
        tracker.init(img, bbox)
        self.bbox = bbox
        self.tracker = tracker


    def getHorizontalPosition(self):
        horizontalCoordinate = self.bbox[1] * self.conversionFactor
        return self.horizontalPosition

    def getVerticalPosition(self):

        verticalCoordinate = self.bbox[0] * self.conversionFactor
        return self.verticalPosition

    def runCamera(self):
        def drawBox(img, bbox):
            # Get coordinates.
            # x is the pixel value corresponding to horizontal movement of the object.
            # (i.e. x = 0 is the far left of the screen, bigger number is further to the right)
            # y is the pixel value corresponding to vertical movement of the object.
            x, y, w, h = int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), ((x + w), (y + h)), (255, 0, 255), 3, 1)
            cv2.putText(img, "Tracking", (25, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 255), 2)

        timer = cv2.getTickCount()
        success, img = self.cap.read()


        success, bbox = self.tracker.update(img)

        if success:
            drawBox(img, bbox)
        else:
            cv2.putText(img, "Lost", (25, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer)
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (25, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)


        cv2.imshow("Tracking", img)

        #if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            #break

camera1 = MachineVisionCamerasAFAM(cameraNumber=0)

while True:
    camera1.runCamera()
    print("X Coordinate (micrometers): " + str("%.2f" % camera1.horizontalPosition))
    print(camera1.horizontalPosition)
    print("Y Coordinate (micrometers): " + str("%.2f" % camera1.verticalPosition))
    print(camera1.verticalPosition)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your `getXXXPosition` methods, which seem to calculate something, are never called. Even if you call them, make sure that you assign the new value to `self.xxxPosition`. At least this is my first impression because you get only zeros in the video.

Comment: After watching the first video, I realized there is much more missing...

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
Off-site links are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
Your posted code is not minimal.
We also expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really matters in your case is the commented `waitKey`, which is needed for the update. As a first step you can replace the commented two lines by `cv2.waitKey(1)`. The continuous updates should start working again.